# I want to add css styling to a button by adding two different flat colors to that button

Tags: html, css

I want to add css styling to a button by adding two different flat colors to that button. left half of the button must be in blue and right half of the button have to be red.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gradient as background and stop the first color at 50% and start the second at 50%:

```css
button {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue 50%, red 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(blue 50%, red 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(blue 50%, red 50%);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

If you want to change to angle of the gradient's direction just use `Xdeg` at the beginning:

```css
button {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-60deg, blue 50%, red 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(-60deg, blue 50%, red 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-60deg, blue 50%, red 50%);;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-60deg, blue 50%, red 50%);;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: yes exactly the same . i used this, but i need to make that horizontal separation to be like facing 60 degrees .

Comment: Like this? background: linear-gradient(60deg, blue 50%, red 50%);

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```css
button{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue 50%, red 50%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, blue 50%, red 50%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, blue 50%, red 50%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 50%); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<button>Click here</button>
```